# Want to set the branch for the deployment section in circle.yml as an dynamic option

Tags: circleci

Is there any way in which I can pass the branch as a dyanamic variable to circle.yml.

example:

suppose I want to deploy a 'random_new' branch to server if all test are green how can I achive that in circle.yml

```
    deployment:
     staging: 
     branch: $dynamic_branch || master
     commands:
      - curl -X POST https://hooks.cloud66.com/stacks/redeploy/my_cloud_redeploy_url
```

more details [here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/want-to-set-the-the-branch-for-the-deployment-section-in-circle-yml/5154)

Comment: How/when would you set `$dynamic_branch`?

Comment: @FelicianoTech I can set it as an environment variable, but I am unable to find a way in which I can tell circleci, use the env variable value to set the deployment branch name in circle.yml

Comment: Have you tried to execute Bash like syntax? Something like `$(echo "hey!")`